# Environment.NewLine list display

Tags: c#, list, task, environment, freeze

I have switch display between already exist lists without any parallel or preceding process to create it. Only thing I need is display of complete separate already exist list by switching with textbox, each size of display is about 7000 lines, but each line is also the set or several strings, so it is large output about 25.0 MB size of text.

I've tried to use several different task methods, but not sure if it is proper way for this case. Anyway all this methods works good if I use it for asynchronous display with `await` for preceding or parallel processing, which is successfully handled by task.

But what I have to do with `Environment.NewLine` which freezes GUI for few seconds, I can't move form over the screen between pressing on button and display of text.

Why same display is completely handled with task if I have it with preceding process which also creates list with huge calculation process in addition to the load, without any problems. But if I want only display already exist list, I have this short time hanging, when `Environment.NewLine` in task is used absolutely same way.

So I don't have any list formation process attached to display, lists are already exist, and goal is somehow display it without this short GUI hanging.

```
private void PART()
{       
    if (a != 0)
    {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list3);             
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list4);             
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (b == 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list1);             
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list2);             
        }
    }
}
```

Same result with:

```
textBox1.Lines = list1.ToArray();
```

Comment: Which part of this is taking the time? The `string.Join`, or the assignment to `Text`? The `string.Join` would be easy to move to a background thread; the assignment to `Text` *can't* be moved to a background thread.

Comment: @Joe White Hello, seems like it is assignment to Text as text is large, but I'm not sure. I don't know  how  to move string.Join to background thread properly in this case to check

Comment: Split it into two lines (`var x = string.Split(...)` and `textBoxN.Text = x`), and then single-step in the debugger and watch the [PerfTips](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/08/18/perftips-performance-information-at-a-glance-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/). Or use [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) to see how long each line takes.